# Obtain all pages with a specific tag in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, taxonomy

I'm creating a custom php page with Wordpress and I want to obtain a list with the pages that contain a specific tag_id with the `taxonomy = "post_tag"`(a Identifier of a given wordpress tag)... I have been searching in the API, but I wasn't able to find out this...
It seems I could use mysql queries to obtain the id of the pages, although I would prefer to use the API or cleaner alternatives. Could someone give me any cleaner solution for this?

Comment: Use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) with `post_type=pages` and `tax_query` for your taxonomy and term.

Comment: Mmm pages don't support tags, unless you give them this feature. So, i mean, do you want to list all POSTS for a specific tag?

Comment: @elclanrs, could you give an example of use? I'm using something like `$args = array("post_type" => "pages","tax_query" => array("taxonomy" => "post_tag","field" => "id","terms" => $t->term_id)); $query = new WP_Query( $args );`
but it doesn't seems to work :S

Comment: Yeah, iEmanuele is right. I would suggest you create your own post type. It should be easier that way.

Comment: Mmmm... In my case, I want to use tags because I'm creating functionality using multiple taxonomy, I don't know if the own post type is useful for me.

Comment: I agree with @elclanrs, you might use a custom post type, which as post, it can easily support tag feature. Does it sound good?

Comment: And of course, @fcortes, what you have tried above fits right.

Answer (score 0):

if you are php inclined you could utilise wp rewrite rules to map a page url to a tag page. i'm not so good with wp but something like:

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );
function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $new_rules = array( 'tag/(.+?)$' => 'index.php?tags=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) );
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + (array)$wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

you need to flush rules, either by visiting the Settings -> Permalink page or calling `flush_rewrite_rules();`